# Cron Job in Openshift not a valid Template but *batch.CronJob with yml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to make a `cron job` in Openshift but I got this error:

```
error: unable to parse "openshift/cronJob-template.yml", not a valid Template but *batch.CronJob
```

I ran this command:

```
oc process -f openshift/cronJob-template.yml -p namespace=test-project | oc apply -f -
```

My `yml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            parent: "demo"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: demo
            image: demo
            command: ["java",  "-jar", "test.jar"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I did have my schedule looking like the following but I am not sure if it is correct in a `yml` file `schedule: "*/30 2 * * * /tmp/logs"`

This is my first time creating a cron job via `yml`and on Openshift so I apologise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template looks ok. Try run `oc create -f openshift/cronJob-template.yml -n test-project` instead.

Comment: I can accept this answer in 5 min. What about the logs? Is there a way I can set them in this yaml file?

Comment: Yeah, after the job has been scheduled at least once, running `oc get pods` should show a completed job. At that point, run `oc logs <completed-pod-name>`. The yaml file is the definition of the resource. It will never contain the logs.

Comment: That is confusing. Yeah and then you say it will never contain logs?

Comment: Sorry. Meant logs are viewable but yaml is not related in any way to the logs